# need to remove border from searchbar

Tags: html, css, reactjs

So I have searchbar when I don't click on it, it appers like below image[image]

but as soon as I type something there appears a blue border but I don't want it and I don't know how to reMove it[image]

this is the css file

```
body{
    background: whitesmoke;
}
.header{
    display: flex;
    /* width:50%; */
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border-bottom: 1px solid whitesmoke;
}

.header-middle {
    display:flex;
    flex:0.5;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.header-middle > .MuiSvgIcon-root {
    color: grey;
    background: transparent;
}

.header-middle > input {
    border:none;
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
    outline-width: 0;
    font-size: medium;
    background-color: white;
  }
```

this is the github repo:[github repo](https://github.com/yashkr18/Hacker-News)

Comment: Can you put the relevant component code as well ?

Comment: plesase add a [repro] for debugging details that incl. HTML

Comment: I have added the github repo

Answer (score 0):

By default there is a border for your input when its focused. So in order to get rid of the border when the input is fouced, you can add this to your css:

```
.header-middle > input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for your input use

```
input {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in an [edit] to help future readers understand it. Code-only answers might help the OP in this case but might not help someone finding this question later down the road.